# Java 8 - How to sort a list of bson documents by multiple fields?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, document, bson

In Java, I've a `List<Document>` where Document is bson document.  This list gets populated from the mongoDB.

Document class is nothing but `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`

In our case, we store json documents (from Mongo) into this Document class.

**Example**: Document is a key value pair representation of the following json. Note that the structure of the json and the nested levels can vary for every document.

```
{
    "assetType" : "EQUITY", 
    "cusip" : "g5asds6",    
    "symbol" : "BqrF",        
    "pricing" : {
        "eodAskPrice" : 4.168816,        
        "eodBidPrice" : 4.164947,
        "eodPriceCurrency" : "USD",
        "eodPriceCurrencyDesc" : "US Dollar",
        "prevEodAskPrice" : 4.079388,
        "prevEodBidPrice" : 4.058687,        
    },
    "reference" : {                
        "adrSponsored" : false,
        "countryIncorp" : "LU",
        "countryIncorpDesc" : "LUXEMBOURG",        
        "dtc" : {
            "bookEntryDrsFlag" : false,
            "bookEntryDrsFlagDesc" : "Ineligible",
            "specialDepReasonType" : "REG",
            "specialDepReasonTypeDesc" : "Regular"
        },
        "estimatedAnnualDividend" : 0.0,
        "exchangeCode" : "%",
        "exchangeCodeDesc" : "Other-OTC",
    }
}
```

**My question is** , how do I write some sort of a custom comparator so sort my List based on fields specified by the user?

Note that, **I can't create getters** for these fields.

One user can specify sort-by ["symbol", "exchangeCode"] and another can specify ["cusip", reference.countryIncorp", "countryIncorpDesc"]

Also note that I can't do this sorting in Mongo. Since the data is available in memory, I have to sort this in-memory.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you also considering the pageable object or are you getting all elements from db and sorting on java ?

Comment: instead of fetching the data and sorting on list, why you are sorting in db and getting sorted result depending the user input? is there any issue on that?

Comment: The <Document> will have the necessary cache-able elements retrieved from DB. Sorting should happen on Java in memory. This is just to avoid unnecessary DB lookups. Since we have a local cache already for other purposes, we thought of using it to fetch the data if the requested data is in memory.

Comment: Why don't you allow DB to do what it's optimized to do and create a query (complicate enough) with the user input and the sorting params? Either way you won't send the query before the user ask for it so the sorting params would be available to you. Sorting it in memory would be a bad idea considering the amount of documents you could receive... Also Mongo returns a cursor, so you have to iterate all documents first (to create a list) and then sort them

Comment: Dimitris, I agree with you. Since the data is already in memory, we thought we can avoid DB calls. But sorting seem to be bottleneck here.